# Connecting a usb flash drive to a MacBook Pro

Tags: mac, usb, macbook, usb-storage, usb-flash-drive

I need to read some files from a usb thumb drive, but I plug it into my MBP, nothings happens. I was expecting it to mount automatically.  Is this normal?

The same drive works fine with Windows Vista.

Comment: What file system is on your thumb drive?  It sounds like OS-X doesn't recognize it.

Comment: It's FAT. Not sure if FAT 16 or FAT32

Comment: Take a look in System Profiler and Disk Utility -- do they see it, and what do they say about it?  Note: in Disk Utility, use the Info button in the toolbar for full details.

Comment: Does absolutely nothing happen?  Not even a pop-up window giving you a few options to do with unrecognized disk?

Comment: Nope, nothing at all. :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only "solution" was to erase the disk with "disk utility". Now it's visible both on my MBP as well as my Windows machines. Not really a solution, but…